# Decideing on Which method to run C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, methods

I was wondering if in c# there was kind of like an if and else statement for methods like an example would be

```
 private void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   if the ComputerSelectionmethod runs and executes don't execute the FindOpenCellCols method below
   {

        ComputersSelection();
        FindOpenCellCols();
    } 
   }
```

Comment: `if/else` statements only require a boolean value that an expression can evaluate to.  Have your method return a boolean, and you're all set

Comment: Your sample is not very clear... What do you mean "method runs and executes"? Do you expect that method never terminate? Or throw exception? Or return value? Or have timeout?

Comment: As @AlexeiLevenkov says, "method runs and executes" is not very clear. The closest thing I can think of is "the method runs and returns without throwing an exception".  In that case, look at @Selman22#'s answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
bool control = true;
try
{
    ComputersSelection();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    control = false;
}

if(!control) FindOpenCellCols();
```

I assume you mean runs and successfully executes by *"runs and executes"*.

Comment: Why not just `try { ComputersSelection(); } catch (Exception) { FindOpenCellCols(); }`?

Answer (score 0):

If you change the `control` variable to `false` in `catch` body, `exception` may have thrown in last lines of code in that case `ComputersSelection()` method's most part is executed and still `FindOpenCellCols()` would be executed. Try the below code

```
public bool control = true;

ComputersSelection()
{
   .......
   code;
   .......
   control = false;
}

if(control)
{
   FindOpenCellCols();

}
```